# Properly Created Windows Share with Different Permissions

Tags: windows, network-share, password, file-permissions, file-sharing

In my network, I have 3 workstations and 1 server.

I want the user at each computer to be able to save their files to a share on the server. Each user should have their own directory.

As the names of the users may change I have created user accounts with the names of the computers they are assigned to.

I would like to make sure that each user is only able to access their files not the files of the other users.

My problem is when I give permission to access the share on the server to the user Workstation 1, the Workstation 1 user is not able to access the files. The user Workstation 1 gets the error about sharing permissions are not available contact your network administrator.

Comment: I am going to rewrite this question some. Some of the things in this question are inaccurate.

Comment: Are these in a domain, a workgroup, or a homegroup? What OS are each of those computers running?

Comment: these are not in domain or homegroup. each is connected to a work network.

Comment: Work network is not a valid answer. Either the computers are joined to a domain or they are in a workgroup. Knowing which one is necessary to provide you the proper advice.

Comment: I have not configured domain. if workgroup is default then they are in workgroup.

Comment: If they are in a workgroup this becomes mildly more complicated as Windows interprets usernames as username@domain. If you are in a workgroup (not joined to a domain) then the username is user@computer. That means you need to properly pass the workstation1@server username and not the workstation1@workstation1 username to the server. What you want to do is best done with a domain instead of workgroups.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are trying to set the permissions only in the share, this will not work.

You need to give all three computers permissions on the share, so they can connect to it.

Then you can use the permissions on the file system to define which computer can access which files on the server.

```
Share Folder     <- allow all computers in the share permission
 |---- Folder A  <- allow only Computer A on the filesystem
 |---- Folver B  <- allow only Computer B on the filesystem
 `---- Folder C  <- allow only Computer C on the filesystem
```

Another option would be to create separate shares for each computer, but the above option should suffice.

Comment: can you explain some more.

Comment: I share folder A to comp A. folder B to comp B. I.e. separate folders and user account for each comp.

Comment: @neogeomat I added a schema for clarification